# Powershell - helping with our CMDB Issue - Opinions?

Tags: powershell, cmdb

recently I took it upon myself to learn Powershell.  It was a rough 2 weeks and a lot of reading but I'm getting better and better.  I had some pressure at work to help with correcting our CMDB.  We are about 7 months away from having a true Depolyment/Asset Management system in place.  We have many reasons for relying on Powershell right now and we're trying to clean up a mess before we get the management system in.  Anyway, I created a script that gets a lot of information for us.  We have about 3000 objects/pcs and we need as much info as possible.  Anyway, I created a script.  So far it works well but I wanted some opinions from the experts or any advice.  I feel like I did a decent job putting this together with only 2 weeks experiance but I really want to know what others think.

One thing I noticed:  Windows 7 Boxes with IE9 and Up do not return a value for IE Version.  Anyone know why?

Please see my code below:

```
    Set-QADPSSnapinSettings -defaultSizeLimit 0


    $FullPCList = (Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot $ou | Sort Name | select  -expand name)

    foreach ($computer in $FullPCList) {
    ping -n 2 $computer >$null
    if($lastexitcode -eq 0) { $Online = "Yes" } else { $Online = "No" }
    $PCInfo = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    $WinInfo = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    $ram = ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1MB)
    $bios = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_Bios -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    $ie = (Get-Wmiobject -ComputerName $computer -namespace “root\CIMV2\Applications\MicrosoftIE” -query “select version from MicrosoftIE_Summary” -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    $freespace = ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Select Freespace | Measure-object Freespace -Sum).Sum / 1GB)


    #Start uptime check
    $LastBootUpTime = $WinInfo.ConvertToDateTime($WinInfo.LastBootUpTime)
    $Time = (Get-Date) - $LastBootUpTime
    $formattime = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $Time.Days, $Time.Hours, $Time.Minutes
    #End Uptime Check

          if ($WinInfo.Caption -match "Windows 7") {
                $name  = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Users" -Exclude "*Service*","*admin*","*Public*","*ffodero*","*jgalli*","*jwalters*","*frochet*" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object Name -First 1).Name
                $loggedintime     = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Users" -Exclude "*Service*","*admin*","*Public*","*ffodero*","*jgalli*" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object LastAccessTime -First 1).LastAccessTime
          }
          if ($WinInfo.Caption -match "Windows XP") {
                      $name                   = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Documents and Settings" -Exclude "*Service*","*admin*","*Public*" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object Name -First 1).Name
                      $loggedintime     = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Documents and Settings" -Exclude "*Service*","*admin*","*Public*" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object LastAccessTime -First 1).LastAccessTime
          }

    $table = @{
          Model = $PCInfo.Model
          IEVersion = $ie.Version
          Serial = $Bios.SerialNumber
          Memory = $ram
          DriveFreeSpaceGB = $freespace
          Manufacturer = $PCInfo.Manufacturer
          OSName = $WinInfo.Caption
          Computer = $computer
          Uptime = $formattime
          LastloggedinUser = $name
          LastLoggedinDate = $loggedintime
          LoggedOnDuringScan = $PCInfo.Username
          ServicePack = $WinInfo.ServicePackMajorVersion
          Online = $Online
                }
          New-Object PSObject -Property $table | Export-Csv C:\logs\mother.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace `root\CIMV2\Applications\MicrosoftIE` has been [removed starting with Windows Vista](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/09/how-can-i-determine-which-version-of-internet-explorer-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx) (see note at the end of the blog post). You should be able to read the version number from the registry, though:

```
$hive = [UInt32]'0x80000002'
$key  = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer'

$reg = [WMIClass]"\\$computer\root\default:StdRegProv"
$ieVersion = $reg.GetStringValue($hive, $key, 'Version').sValue
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've also come across another problem.  $name and $logggedintime both return values when there is nothing to return.  I am assuming its posting the previous variable to the table.  How do i prevent it from doing this?  This only happens if the PC is offline or RPC Service is unavailable for if i get access denied for some reason.

Comment: The variables might retain values from a previous iteration. Unset variables before use to prevent that (e.g. `$var = $null` or `Remove-Variable var -EA SilentlyContinue`).